# Why an android application becomes slower to respond

Tags: android, nook

I had an android app built especially for medium screen size android devices.
Now it was required to build that same app for a device called **nook-color** (by Barnes & Noble)

So for this we made all the images bigger & size & changed the layouts.
The result is that the apk which was 97.5 Mb earlier has now become 124 Mb in size.

Now the testers have complained that the application has become slower and it  takes a little longer for any screen to open up. I am wondering whether this is due to bigger images or there is something else. 
Can you please tell me what could be the reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

124 Mb for an app seems to be a little bit excessive.  I'd suggest trying to scale down the image assets, use [Nine Patch images](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html), as well as using [PNGCrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The delays are (at least in part) due to loading larger images (de-compressing them to bitmaps, to be more exact). Unless you can't help it, you should attempt to convert as many of these images to 9-patches : http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html.